# Can not reset MariaDB password "can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, password, password-recovery

When I go

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

This message is outputted.

```
170802 14:14:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

When I try to run `mariadb`, I get

```
$ mariadb
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

When I check the logs, I don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `mysqld_safe` silently fails if it doesn't have permissions and it can't write to the log as in the event of being run as a regular user.

Instead run,

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```